# ASP.Net web forms best practice to replace text in a Literal control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, literals

This is an easy question that I'm looking your input on.

I'm looking for the best practice to replace a piece of text from the code behind in the literal control.

The aspx markup looks like this and I'm replacing value in the link where it says {0}:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litViewLightingCollections" Visible="false">
    <span class="disclaimer">
        <div style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <a href="/LightingCollections/{0}/default.aspx" >
                <img src="/images/productdetail/elements/icon-lighting-collections.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle"> Lighting Collections
            </a>
        </div>
    </span>
</asp:Literal>
```

So what I have done to call a string.format on the test, which works fine:

```
litViewLightingCollections.Visible = true;
litViewLightingCollections.Text = String.Format(litViewLightingCollections.Text, lightingDictionary[category]);
```

And this works fine, however there are other ways to do this.
What is the best and the most lightweight method to do this?

- I could have another literal control in the href tag and set value of it
- I can create a placeholder in the text like {replaceme} and call String.Replace on lit.text
- Put a property in the code behind and use <%= Property %> (I really don't like this one, since it creates a lot of properties on the page)
- Placing a hyperlink control in the literal (against the light weight)
- What are other options?

Answer (score 0):

If all your attempting to do is replace href there is no reason to use a literal.  One of the whole point of controls is that they allow a more programmatic way to set values.  One way to solve this is to replace the  with a [link button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) and on the onload of the link button set the href in the code behind.  Another solution is to use old style asp tags <%= %> and have the server code automatically replace the needed section.

Comment: The idea is to make it as light weight as possible, I should have mentioned that. I'm uneasy to add another hyperlink control on the page for that reason.

Comment: Then why not just use mvc or generate the entire page.  I doubt either option would be any slower.  The second one I would bet has better performance and has not of the drawback of view state.